# SQL Lag and LEAD query

Tags: sql

[image]

I need data which is in Output column. When 1st column status is P then we need value from Filled date. But once status is anything from P then we need date from last P status. Pls. let me know if i am not able to explain. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard SQL, you can use:

```
select (case when status = 'P'
             then filled_dt
             else lag(case when status = 'P' then filled_dt end) over (partition by mbr_id order by filled_dt ignore nulls)
        end) as imputed_filled_dt
```

This is standard SQL; however, not all databases support `ignore nulls`.  This probably does what you want:

```
select (case when status = 'P'
             then filled_dt
             else max(case when status = 'P' then filled_dt end) over (partition by mbr_id order by filled_dt)
        end) as imputed_filled_dt
```